# Basic authentication and passing token to next endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, token

I am new to basic authentication and tokens.

I have been playing around with postman in order to get a token using basic authentication and then passing the token as a bearer token to access another endpoint. I wanted to know how I would code this into api calls using node and express.

I know that for Basic auth I need to encode the client id and secret into base64

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:8080/token/ \
--header 'authorization: Basic ***' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 
         grant_type=credentials
```

The token I get from the above call I want to pass onto the below call

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:8080/login \
--header 'authorization: Bearer ***' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 
         user=1
```

How would this like as code in a node application

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend json web token aka jwt for this purpose.

Right now I code REST API in express, mongodb, and I am using jwt for auth.
Since I dont use any frontend framework or lib, I use cookie for jwt token storage.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const generateToken = (res, id, auth_level) => {

  const token = jwt.sign({id, 
                          auth_level
                        }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
    expiresIn: '7d'
  });

  return res.cookie('token', token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 15),
    secure: false, 
    httpOnly: true,
  });
};

module.exports = generateToken
```

In this example I call this function on sucessful login try. And after that on every route access, using middleware I try to resolve if user have this token and try to resolve token.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// Verify user token from cookie
const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {

    // Get token from cookie named token
    const token = req.cookies.token || '';

    try {

        // Check if cookie exists, maybe expired maybe user didnt have one - no login
        if (!token) {
            return next();
        }

        // Decrypt users jwt token and get information
        const decrypt = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);

        // Pass that infomation to request user object
        req.user = {
            id: decrypt.id,
            auth_level: decrypt.auth_level,
            test: 'test'
        };

        // Continue with exectution of app
        return next();

    } catch (err) {

        return res.status(500).json(err.toString());

    }
};

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

If this token is valid, I pass custom user object to req object.

After this I protect routes with custom middlewares. Code is inspired by [this](https://dev.to/mr_cea/remaining-stateless-jwt-cookies-in-node-js-3lle) tutorial, would recommend it.